# Generate all paths/routes through 2D array in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm working in Java. Given a matrix NxM, I need to find all possible paths through the array. It is only allowed to go diagonally up or down, or go to the right. An example 4x4 matrix:

```
3  5  7  9
2  4  6  8
9  3  7  5
6  8  2  4
```

The numbers in the matrix can be any arbitrary value. I would like to generate all possible routes through the matrix, starting in one of the four numbers in the first column. It is only allowed to move Northeast, East, and Southeast. An example route:

```
3-5 7 9
   \
2 4 6-8
9 3 7 5
6 8 2 4
```

So all routes consist of M numbers. I'm using a 2D array to hold this NxM matrix. Some more possible paths are:

```
3 4 6 5
3 5 6 9
9 4 7 4
9 3 6 9
```

Is there a way to easily generate all paths in Java?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like some pretty standard path finding. Using a depth first search or breadth first. What have you tried and why isn't it working?

Comment: I have no idea, this question is almost 9 years old 

Comment: Ha! The number of times I do that, I just see it come up in the list and don't even bother checking the date.

Comment: No worries, I thought it was funny  thanks for the help anyways

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can use three methods for doing this and call them recursively.

1. goNortEast(); Search for an element to the index [N-1][M+1] if N>0, else there will be no element NOrtEast of the current element, if element exists this will also lead to a new path.
2. goEast(); Each element can go East by index [N][M+1];
3. goSouthEast(); Search for element at index [N+1][M+1] if the element exists, this will also lead to a new path,

Call these three methods on each element starting from [0][0], then [1][0] and so on.

for [0][0], it will call goNorthEast[]- will not satisfy condition goEast();-index[0][1] and goSouthEast(); index[1][1] now call the same three methods of these elements.

At the end you will get all possible paths from the element you started.

Comment: http://ekiras.blogspot.in/2014/10/program-to-find-all-paths-in-matrix-of-2d-array.html view this link to see a sample program